# C# Form MultiThreading, Need a tricky solution

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I have a problem about using multithreading in c#. I have a complex computing thing that must run on the main thread means it must run on the main window.

My program runs like this :

- First it will open a new window and user can input parameter
- Then it will run a complex computing that must run in the main thread ( i can't change this, i'm using library that prevent call the computing thing in different thread, if i'm using different thread it will come with an exception).
- When the simulation run, it will also open a new window that monitoring the computing, it will also plot the graphic for it, and i need it to be real time.

**Problem:** Since the long time complex computing is running on the main thread, the monitoring window will be hang and not responding. Is there any tricky way to solve this? Can i use different thread to run the monitoring window? the main form is okay for not responding, but not okay for monitoring window. Here i put some code that resembles my program, not my real program, but the flow is the same.

**Main Form**(main thread that will run the computing thing,and input parameter from user)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        compute c = new compute();
        c.computing();
    }
}
```

**Graph Form** (Monitoring Graph that will plot chart, needed to be real time)

```
    public graphic()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void updateLabel(int count)
    {
        label1.Text = "Current i value:  " + count;
    }
```

**Compute class** (doing the computing thing)

```
class compute
{
    delegate void writeToForm(int i);
    graphic g = new graphic();

    public compute()
    {
        g.Show();
    }
    public void computing()
    {
       //THIS PART MUST RUN ON THE MAIN THREAD, DON'T MAKE IT ON THE OTHER THREAD
       //IT IS A MUST
        int count = 0;
        //THIS IS THE LONG TIME COMPUTING THING
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            count += i;
            updateLabel(count);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }

    private void updateLabel(int count)
    {
        if (g.InvokeRequired)
        {
            g.Invoke(new writeToForm(updateLabel), new object[] { count });
            return;
        }
        g.updateLabel(count);
    }
}
```

I can't do anything about the method must run in the main thread, i'm using library that prevent its method to be ran from other method, thanks..

Comment: If this thingy needs to run on the main thread, is it simply the case that it has thread affinity with the thread the object is created on?  I had this issue with some COM stuff.  Solving it was basically create the COM object on the thread you want it to run on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround would be to write your monitoring form in another program, which can be launched by your main program before the `computing` method is executed. Yes, your main form will still hang (but you say this isn't a problem?).

You could communicate with your main application, possibly by opening a local TCP connection (which can run on a different thread without a problem). This could send commands to the monitoring application (or any other connected TCP clients if you wish), which would receive these and use the `Control.Invoke` method to update the UI.

Comment: hmm. quite interesting solution

Answer (score 1):

If it is must for you to perform computation in the main thread, modify your code as below

```
public void computing()
    {
       //THIS PART MUST RUN ON THE MAIN THREAD, DON'T MAKE IT ON THE OTHER THREAD
       //IT IS A MUST
        int count = 0;
        //THIS IS THE LONG TIME COMPUTING THING
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            count += i;
            updateLabel(count);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Application.DoEvents(); //tell windows to process pending message.
        }
    }
```

Comment: oh that's what i'm looking for all day, thanks a lot.., quite lag on process, but thats okay, it's running at least, and in real time

Comment: emm, i forgot something, my real program the counting will take a long time to run, for example the line count+=i in my real program will do some method that will for maybe two minutes, that will make my window not responding for 2 minutes, right? can't it be to be responding all the time?

Comment: Exactly, your program does not respond in that case for certain time. The solution would be move your computation code run in other thread or Create a timer and do Application.DoEvents in its tick event.

Comment: i'm using timer and it still not responding at all, can i run the graphic form in different thread, i read about it in internet, but the said that it's not thread safe, is it true? so is there no any way at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and call `Application.DoEvents` after updating the graph in the second window. This processes all window messages, which should allow your second window to be updated.